# Can I delete the modifier of a method with Javassist?

Tags: annotations, javassist

everyone.

I have a class file.

```
public class ClsSync {
     public synchronized void biat(){
     }    
}
```

I want to change it to

```
public  void biat(){   // delete the synchronized keyword
}
```

Can I implement it using Javassist?
 How can I add an annotation to the method of a class file with javassist? 
Any suggestions are welcome!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
    ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass cc = cp.get("ClsSync");

    CtMethod cm = cc.getDeclaredMethod("biat");
    cm.setModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC);
```

Just use [CtMethod#setModifiers()](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtBehavior.html#setModifiers%28int%29) to set the required mask.

Comment: He might want to leave other flags as-is, then it would be better to use cm.setModifiers(cm.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.ABSTRACT) (removes "abstract" modifier while leaving all other as-is).